# What is wrong with this C++ main method driver to run this method?

Tags: c++, driver

I'm doing C++ this semester (just finished learning Java) and using Codewars to get some practice (this has been my most effective way of practicing but it only requires the method not the driver) with my C++ coding but unsure how to create the driver for this method so I can practice in my IDE.

What am I missing here in the main so it runs in my IDE? The solution (not my code) works but my main method doesn't drive it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <unordered_set>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
using namespace std;
cout << is_isogram("Dermatoglyphics"); //error: use of undeclared identifier 'is_isogram'
}

bool is_isogram(std::string str) { //warning: Function is never used
std::unordered_set<char> char_set;
for (const auto &c : str) {
    auto c_lower = std::tolower(c);
    if (char_set.count(c_lower) == 0) char_set.insert(c_lower);
    else return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: `is_isogram` ought to be declared before it it referenced in `main`. Either add a [declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) for it above `main`, or move the whole definition above `main`.

Comment: Cammo, you may not have the ability to upvote but you *always* have the ability to accept an answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo I didn't know that, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the point where you try to *use* `is_isogram()` in `main()`, it has not actually been declared yet, hence the "use of undeclared identifier" <sup>(a)</sup>.

You can solve this in one of two ways, the first being to declare it with a function prototype before use, such as with:

```
bool is_isogram(std::string);           # declare
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {      # define
    // main stuff
}
bool is_isogram(std::string str) {      # define
    // is_isogram stuff
}
```

And the second is to swap `is_isogram()` and `main()` so that the declaration is done as part of the definition (defining something implicitly declares it):

```
bool is_isogram(std::string str) {      # define
    // is_isogram stuff
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {      # define
    // main stuff
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The second reported issue, "function not used", is almost certainly just a side-effect of the first. Because the compiler couldn't do anything with the `is_isogram()` call from `main()`, it just throws it away after reporting the error. As a result, there is now no code that calls your function when you define it.

Comment: A declaration is not done as part of a definition.   The relationship is the reverse of that - a definition is actually a type of declaration  (i.e. all definitions are declarations, not all declarations are definitions).

Comment: @Peter, I think you may have misunderstood. I did not say a declaration is a type of definition, I said that, if you do a definition, the declaration is created as a part of that. In other words, we're saying the same thing. If you think there's a clearer way for me to say it beyond my added parenthetical (which hopefully clarifies), I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: No we're not saying the same thing.

Comment: @Peter: okay, tell me how they're different, exactly. Because it seems to me "a definition including an implicit declaration" and "all definitions are declarations" is rather the same thing. I *may* be misunderstanding what you're saying but it seems pretty clear at the moment.

Comment: Thanks kindly to everyone for your replies, now I can get to practicing :)